# ConnectionError when making request to API url

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I'm trying to make a request for the API url below but it always gives an error, but I tried everything but it doesn't work. Below is the code I am using and the error message that appears.

```
import requests
import json
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Custom user agent'})

resposta_estados = session.get('https://transparencia.registrocivil.org.br/api/record/birth')
resposta_estados = resposta_estados.json()
```

**Mensage error:**

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='transparencia.registrocivil.org.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/record/birth (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7df8142220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it's a issue on your pc, not with the code. When I run it, it responds with:

{'data': [{'name': 'AC', 'total': 680237}, {'name': 'AL', 'total': 1643306}, {'name': 'AP', 'total': 450789}, {'name': 'AM', 'total': 495797}, {'name': 'BA', 'total': 6881830}, {'name': 'CE', 'total': 5147421}, {'name': 'DF', 'total': 1879978}, {'name': 'ES', 'total': 3494918}, {'name': 'GO', 'total': 2437212}, {'name': 'MA', 'total': 1073548}, {'name': 'MT', 'total': 604919}, {'name': 'MS', 'total': 951403}, {'name': 'MG', 'total': 20504981}, {'name': 'PA', 'total': 1168653}, {'name': 'PB', 'total': 928077}, {'name': 'PR', 'total': 12320373}, {'name': 'PE', 'total': 12335456}, {'name': 'PI', 'total': 372917}, {'name': 'RJ', 'total': 3822456}, {'name': 'RN', 'total': 679628}, {'name': 'RS', 'total': 7102045}, {'name': 'RO', 'total': 1001691}, {'name': 'RR', 'total': 184689}, {'name': 'SC', 'total': 4429188}, {'name': 'SP', 'total': 50223570}, {'name': 'SE', 'total': 1219199}, {'name': 'TO', 'total': 442558}], 'total': 142476839, 'status': 1}

Since I can't look at it in person, I would suggest clearing the cached data for the webpage. Also, try typing in the website link manually. If it responds with an error, than your internet it causing an interruption. Finally, the error you got signifies that you sent too many requests to a public server.

If you want more reference, check out this site:
https://linuxpip.org/fix-max-retries-exceeded-with-url-error-python/